# I am working on a month program that gives back the number of days in that month, but somethings not right

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small program that takes the month number and convert it into the days that month has. 
If someone can please point our some of the wrong coding i have that would be great. And please i am not trying to import calendar as i am trying to have it very simple.  Thanks
-Joel

```
try:
month = int(input("Enter a month Number from 1 - 12: "))
#February
if month == 2:
    print("28 or 29 Days")
else:
    #31 day months
    if month in(1 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 8 , 10 , 12):
        print("31 Days")
        #Rest of the months 
        if month in(2 , 4 , 6 , 9 , 11):
            print("30 Days")
    #Invalid input

except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

**EDIT:** I have updated the code a bit but i am still getting a logic error whenever a number larger than 12 is entered. Looking to get an "invalid answer" print statement when a number other than 1-12 are typed.

```
 #Enter a month Number from 1 - 12: 100
 #>>>
```

Comment: `if month in set( (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) ):`

Answer (score 4):

The

```
if month == (1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12):
```

should be

```
if month in {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12}:
```

In your current code, the expression `1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12` is first evaluated and then `month` is compared to the result (which happens to be `1`).

This means that the program only works correctly for `1` (printing `31`) and `2` (printing `28 or 29`); for everything else it falls through to the final `else` clause and prints `30`.

Comment: ... its a dupe ...

Comment: That doesn't answer the question completely. - `200` case.